# Form_Load() doesnt allow sub to be executed VB6

Tags: vb6

While working on a vb6 project, I found that I could not execute a sub (contained in an external module) using form_load(). Here is what the code looked like:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

ExampleSubroutine

End Sub
```

At the time, I circumvented this problem by using form_activate() instead to start up the form:

```
Private Sub form_activate()

ExampleSubroutine

End Sub
```

However, this means that whenever the program switches to a different form and returns to the main form, the sub is run again. I do not want this. Is there a way to execute the sub using form_load()? Thanks.

Comment: What is `ExampleModule` and what does it do?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a module here. Normally you would be calling a Sub or Function within a module so what is `ExampleModule`?

Comment: Don't recall having issues running a Sub from Form_Load. What is in this Sub?

Comment: It draws lines onto a picture box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because `PictureBox` hasn't been fully loaded then. One way to use `Activate` event is have Static Boolean and then set it once it hits the first time.

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()

Static BeenHere as Boolean

If Not BeenHere Then
    ExampleSub
    BeenHere = True
End If

End Sub
```